# Nokogiri and XPath: saving text result of scrape

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri, yaml

I would like to save the text results of a scrape in a file. This is my current code:

```
require "rubygems"
require "open-uri"
require "nokogiri"

class Scrapper
  attr_accessor :html, :single

  def initialize(url)
    download = open(url)
    @page = Nokogiri::HTML(download)
    @html = @page.xpath('//div[@class = "quoteText"andfollowing-sibling::div[1][@class = "quoteFooter" and .//a[@href and normalize-space() = "hard-work"]]]')
  end

  def get_quotes
    @quotes_array = @html.collect {|node| node.text.strip}
    @single = @quotes_array.each do |quote|
      quote.gsub(/\s{2,}/, " ") 
    end
  end
end
```

I know that I can write a file like this:

```
File.open('text.txt', 'w') do |fo|
    fo.write(content)
```

but I don't know how to incorporate @single which holds the results of my scrape. Ultimate goal is to insert the information into a database.

I have come across some folks using Yaml but I am finding it hard to follow the step to step guide.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide more information, either a reduced sample of the HTML, or code that reproduces the problem. "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
@single = @quotes_array.map do |quote|
  quote.squeeze(' ')
end

File.open('text.txt', 'w') do |fo|
  fo.puts @single
end
```

Or:

```
File.open('text.txt', 'w') do |fo|
  fo.puts @quotes_array.map{ |q| q.squeeze(' ') }
end
```

and don't bother creating `@single`.

Or:

```
File.open('text.txt', 'w') do |fo| 
  fo.puts @html.collect { |node| node.text.strip.squeeze(' ') }
end
```

and don't bother creating `@single` or `@quotes_array`.

[`squeeze`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-squeeze) is part of the String class. This is from [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-squeeze):

```
"  now   is  the".squeeze(" ")         #=> " now is the"
```